# How do I add a apt-get repository without editing /etc/apt/sources.list?

Tags: aptitude, yum, repository

I want to add a repository to apt-get (without potentially messing up /etc/apt/sources.list) through the user of a script.  This script may run multiple times so I can't just append the entry each time.  Is there any way I can add a single file in a directory with entries?

I know you can do this for yum, but I'm not sure if it's possible for apt-get.  Please let me know if I need to add more info.

Comment: If you double click on /etc/apt/sources.list, it opens a GUI interface with a wizard for adding repositories.  There is a checkbox where you can enable and disable entries (e.g., to allow use of a new entry only when updating some "foreign" repository software), and entries can be deleted.  It also creates a backup called sources.list.save in the same directory.  If you want extra protection, you can always make a copy of the original file yourself before changing it.  So there isn't much risk of messing up the file if you are going the script route just for that reason.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can place files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.  This is described in the man page for `sources.list` (type `man sources.list`).  The man page says:

> Older SOURCES.LIST.D
>
> The /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory provides a way to add sources.list entries in separate files. The format is the same
> as for the regular sources.list file. File names need to end with .list and may only contain letters (a-z and A-Z), digits
> (0-9), underscore (_), hyphen (-) and period (.) characters. Otherwise they will be silently ignored.

UPDATE:

> 2016 SOURCES.LIST.D
>
> The /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory provides a way to add sources.list entries in separate files. Two different file formats are allowed as described in the next two sections. Filenames need to have either the extension .list or .sources depending on the contained format. The filenames may only contain letters (a-z and A-Z), digits (0-9), underscore (_), hyphen (-) and period (.) characters. Otherwise APT will print a notice that it has ignored a file, unless that file matches a pattern in the Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently configuration list - in which case it will be silently ignored.

Answer (score 8):

You could try:

```
add-apt-repository <REPOSITORY LINE>
```

The repository line would just be what you would append to the sources.list or a PPA repository. Check out the manpage [here](http://man.he.net/man1/add-apt-repository), or execute:

```
man add-apt-repository
```

Comment: From a quick look at the man file for add-apt-repository it looks like it simply appends the line to the sources.list file, it doens't mention if it checks, so this is just the same as "echo line >> sources.list" which I already had.  Thanks for responding though.

Comment: @Daisetsu I know it does, I thought you just felt uncomfortable manually editing the file! Must've misunderstood! Great you got an answer that worked for you though!

Answer (score 1):

I (thought that I) needed to add a ppa repo to a crunchbang, (debian) install:
(**N.B.** "raring" is the ubuntu version that matched the version of debian that I was using) so I did:

```
sudo su -

# you can call the file anything that you want, but it has to end with .list to be a valid for apt-get
echo 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/ raring main'>> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/boot-repair.list

# get the keys for that repo so that apt can verify the signed .deb files
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/dists/raring/Release.gpg
apt-key add Release.gpg
#gpg --search-keys 60D8DA0B

apt-get update
```

Most of this is explained on the [boot-repair](https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/boot-repair) page, (though in the end [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and then [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) were what I actually needed to restore a lost partition and a corrupted MBR.) This probably isn't *The* Debian way (TM) but it worked for me.

Some debian repos are the "old style" and then you only need a line like:

```
deb http://repo.alexx.net/apt/ /
# the trailing slash needs to be there
```

add-apt-repository is good if you have it, but that seems to be more ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

`add-apt-repository` has a third form (besides PPA URLs and full apt lines), which enables distribution components:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository contrib
```

This was introduced in 12.10 (Quantal).

Comment: it shows `Error: 'contrib' invalid`  using Ubuntu 16.04